# Stuck at starting Selenium Server Nightwatch end-to-end tests

Tags: node.js, port, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Nightwatch.js (node) End to End Mocha Tests on Chrome suddenly are not running.

It says Starting Selenium Server, and stuck there. I've been trying to find a fix for it, but since it doesn't output any log, I can't really debug anything.

What could be the possible cause for it?

I've tried

1) Redownload latest chromedriver and selenium-standalone

2) Redownload previous version chromdriver and selenium-standalone

3) nightwatch.json (using port 4444, and localhost, it worked perfectly before)

4) change port and host

5) delete all npm package, and reinstall

6) restart

7) disable anti-virus

8) replug internet connection

I installed mouse without border the day before the tests stuck, could it be an issue?

Comment: If you add a path for `log_path` in the config under the `selenium` settings you should get a debug log file after each run with some more details that will help you determine what is going wrong. I have mine set to `selenium: { log_path: 'logs' }` and it outputs a selenium-debug.log file after each session.

Comment: @tehbeardedone Thanks, I've tried adding a log path, but it doesn't output anything. It stops 'Starting selenium server...' and forever stucks there

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not running is due to versions clash

1) download JRE v10.0

2) update latest chromedriver.exe and chrome

3) for selenium standalone server, only 3.9.1 is working for chrome v65